# Vim: Visual mode, w (word) marks more than the word

Tags: vim

When I enter Visual mode and press 'w' to select the word under the cursor, it selects the word, plus the following space. eg.:

[image]

I do not want the punctation in this example marked.

Is this just my vim acting like this? 
I'm using spf13 vim configuration.. http://vim.spf13.com/

Comment: If I recall correctly, vim does that on its own.  It's often pretty convenient.  There's probably a way to disable it--somehow.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

<kbd>w</kbd> moves the cursor to the beginning of the next word. What you are looking for is <kbd>e</kbd>, which moves the cursor  to the end of the current word.

Comment: Also, to “select the word under the cursor” more generally (even when the cursor isn’t already at the beginning of the word), the [`iw` “inner word” text object](http://vimdoc.sourceforge.net/htmldoc/motion.html#iw) would work.

Answer (score 2):

Your setting shouldn't be the default vim setting. For example:

```
foo bar
```

if your cursor on `f`, with vim default setting, you press `vw`, `foo b` will be visual selected, not `foo<space>`.

Because the `selection` option default value would be `inclusive` which means, when you visual select with motion, the last char will be in selection.

As you described, your `selection` option could already be set as `exclusive`, you can check that by:`set selection?`

Anyway, either your setting or the vim default one doesn't achieve your goal. You want the `e` motion. check `:h e` and `:h w` for detail and difference.

P.S. Do **NOT** use any vim distribution!